# C#: Sorting an array results in an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, arrays, json, sorting, .net-6.0

I need to sort a JsonArray of JsonObjects by a property, which results in an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: failed to compare two elements in the array.
> Inner Exception: ArgumentException: t least one object must implement IComparable

This baffles me, since as far as I know all objects are of the same type.

This is my code:

```
    private JsonArray sortOnStartTime(JsonArray arrayToSort)
    {
        var testArray = arrayToSort.OrderBy(x => x["startTime"]); //breakpoint here
        // return (JsonArray)JsonNode.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(arrayToSort.OrderBy(x => x["startTime"])));
        return new JsonArray();
    }
```

If I place the breakpoint, then my `Locals` window in Visual Studio reveals the following on `arrayToSort`:

[image]

There are 104 JsonObjects, and after stepping through `x => x["startTime"]`, it turns out that the error occurs when the last JsonObject - which has a startTime of 0 - is encountered.

In what way does this last element differ from the 103 before? What do I have to do to get rid of the exception? I'm using .NET 6.0.

Comment: What is the actual type of that `startTime` with value `0`? The `DebugViewProperty` is just a wrapper and not interesting here.

Comment: Can you convert your json array to json string and post here pls?

Comment: @JeroenMostert `startTime` comes in as part of a POSTed json string. I have updated the image and expanded the last three instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error says - [`JsonValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonvalue?view=net-7.0) (and it's internal inheritor `JsonValueTrimmable<>`) does not implement `IComparable`. If you don't  want to parse json into classes - then you need to extract actual value. In your case it seems something like the following should work:

```cs
var sorted = arrayToSort
    .OrderBy(x => x["startTime"]?.GetValue<double>())
    .ToList();
```